# var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'image/png'}); report Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am working a cordova sample code in my old phone( Samsung GT-N7100 android 4.1.1, API 16 ).

```
var blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: 'image/png' });
```

The above line code will report error as: 
E/Web Console: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor:175

While it works well in the emulator(which is Android 6.0, API 23).

My question:  which android API version cordova file plugin support ? Where can I find out all the platform's version  which cordova's feature were expecting to support?

code and its origins site is here:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#write-to-a-file-

```
function getSampleFile(dirEntry) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://cordova.apache.org/static/img/cordova_bot.png', true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (this.status == 200) {

            var blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: 'image/png' });
            saveFile(dirEntry, blob, "downloadedImage.png");
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: The issue appears to be that the server does not respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://cordova.apache.org/static/img/cordova_bot.png. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Note also, if `this.reponse` is `Blob`, unless appending or changing data of `Blob` it is not necessary to create a new `Blob` from response